# Can we use the same Hyper-V Shieled VM certificate to create more Shielded VMs on a different host?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-11, hyper-v, certificate, tpm

I had 2 shielded VMs on my Windows 11 prior to clean installing it. I had backed up the 2 certificates for signing and encryption. after importing them, I can access my 2 shielded VMs, no problem, but when I create new Shielded VMs, I see 2 more certificates are added to the certificate store. is this expected or is there a way to make my old certificates known to the host guardian service so that it will use them instead of creating new ones, on the new host? I'm perfectly OK with the current behavior, but want to make sure there isn't any method that I'm missing.

Comment: Do you mean the certificates in the `Shielded VM Local Certificates` store? Each VM gets its own certs (they should have the VM name on them).

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Hi, yes, I mean those certificates. each VM doesn't get its own certificate though. each guarded host gets its own certificates. so after I clean installed Windows, I imported the 2 certificates I previously had, and now that I keep creating shielded VMs (for testing), they all use the new pair of certificate. the common name of the both certificates only include the host's device name. what I want to know is whether I can still use the old pair to create new VMs on the new host. I use mostly PowerShell to do it and I tried related cmdlets but no luck yet.

Comment: yep my mistake. It looks like you can reuse certificates when you set up HGS via `New-HgsGuardian`, just specify the existing/imported `-SigningCertificateThumbprint` and `-EncryptionCertificateThumbprint` instead of `-GenerateCertificates`

Comment: I tried and it imported the certificates but creating new shielded VMs generates another pair of certificates. maybe I did something wrong on my end, I'll try it again on a clean system and report back.